# Gradle provided dependencies present in war

Tags: jboss5.x, gradle

I would like to set several dependencies in my war as provided because theses jar are provided by the server.

So I set my build.gradle like this:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

dependencies {
    compile project(':project1')
    providedCompile 'xml-apis:xml-apis:2.0.2',
        'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5',
        'javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:2.1',
        'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2',
        'com.sun.faces:jsf-api:2.1.6',
        'com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:2.1.6',
        'javax.transaction:jta:1.1'
}
```

But when I deploy my generated war in my server, all jars set in provided are present and my server doesn't start.

What is wrong in my configuration ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks correct, and works fine for me. Chances are that the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Just a question, have you try to import the project into eclipse ? May be the problem is here. What is your gradle command line to build the project ? Thanks